# paypal returnURL is not correct

Tags: php, paypal

I set 
`$setECReqDetails->CancelURL = "http://www.someurl.com/cancel";` and
`$setECReqDetails->ReturnURL = "http://www.someurl.com/submit";`

Paypal returns me to 
`http://www.someurl.com/www.someurl.com/cancel` and 
`http://www.someurl.com/www.someurl.com/submit` after a transaction which don't exist. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, I don't. Shouldn't this define it for me?

Comment: The code you are providing is not enough.
It also depends on how your object ($setECReqDetails) is handling the CancelURL and ReturnURL variables.
Try debugging your app and see what values are stored in those variables right after you assign the values and what values are stored in those variables right before sending the call to PayPal.

I suspect your object is building already a URL for you (ex: http://www.someurl.com) and is actually expecting that you provide only what comes after it.
$setECReqDetails->CancelURL = "cancel";
$setECReqDetails->ReturnURL = "return";

Answer (score 0):

The page was being directed correctly, accessing the returnURL page redirected me using a relative path which I wrote incorrectly, this code was fine.